# Commenting on forked code in github

Tags: github

I've forked a repo in Github and, after looking through the code, I'd like to make a comment to communicate information about a specific line of code to the original committer of that line.

So my question is:
If I make the comment right there in my forked version of the file, does the original committer get the comment notification or would I need to make the comment in the original repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No*, unless you mention them directly (using `@`).

What you can do, is on the **original** repository, find the commit (will look something like `https://github.com/username/repository/commits/abc123def456`) then add a comment on the line there. then they *will* be notified